# Difference between wait in stdlib.h and sys/wait

Tags: c, unix, posix, wait

I'm pretty sure there's such question, but I can't find it :\ Anyway, here's the issue:

What is the difference between `wait` in `stdlib.h` and `sys/wait.h` o.O ?

---

In details - I just encountered this problem and I could't compile a simple C program. I isolated the problem and here's what I got:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int status;
    wait( &status );

    return 0;
}
```

If `stdlib.h` is included, I got:

```
$ gcc asd.cpp 
asd.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
asd.cpp:9:16: error: conflicting declaration ‘wait& status’
asd.cpp:8:6: error: ‘status’ has a previous declaration as ‘int status’
```

What *declaration* ? O.o What is `wait` here, that conflicts with `int status`?

I found a thread in the net, where replacing `stdlib.h` with `sys/wait.h` solves the problem, but why is that and what is the difference?

---

***EDIT***: Thanks to sidyll's comment, I changed the file extention - from `.cpp` to `.c` ***and it worked***! I'm shocked :) How is this so different? And still the same question - what is the different between those two `wait`-s ?

Comment: @sidyll: You can use gcc perfectly fine to compile a .cpp file.  The only difference between using gcc and g++ is that if you're doing linking, then g++ will link in the C++ standard library (libstdc++), but gcc will not.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!! Pfffffff.. That's because I edited directly an old C++ file.. WTF o.O How does this matter so much?

Comment: on my machine stdlib.h just includes sys/wait.h

Comment: @Kiril: Standard C defines no `wait` in `stdlib.h` (nor does it define `<sys/wait>`). I've therefore done a few tag changes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the `wait()` in `<sys/wait.h>` is the one you should use.

From the `wait(3)` man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/wait.h>

       pid_t wait(int *status);
```

The `wait` function isn't defined by the ISO C standard, so a conforming C implementation isn't allowed to declare it in `<stdlib.h>` (because it's legal for a program to use the name `wait` for its own purposes).  gcc with glibc apparently does so in its default non-conforming mode, but if you invoke it with `gcc -ansi -pedantic` or `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic`, it doesn't recognize the function name `wait` or the type `pid_t`.

Answer (score 3):

I did gcc -E wait.cpp to dump the actual preprocessor expansions that take place. What I found was that on linux, the header `/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h` is included which pulls in a `union wait { ... }` but the function wait() from sys/wait.h is never pulled in. The same thing happens with the c compilation, but the for whatever reason the compiler does not complain in that case.

To prove this to yourself, you can change your main to declare the wait as a variable rather than a function call, and the compiler will not complain:

```
int main() {
    int status;
    wait w;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that's really interesting :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that GCC stands for *GNU Compiler Collection*, not GNU C Compiler (as many
other tools which were prefixed with a *g*). It's not a C-only compiler. And
many languages are detected by file extensions. Adam Rosenfield is partialy
correct in his comment. Yes, `g++` will add the C++ library in the linker phase,
but that's not the unique difference (more on this later).

To explain how changing the extension solved it, please take a look in this text
straight from GCC's manual:

> **`Compiling C++ Programs`**
>
> `C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes`**`.C, .cc, .cpp,`**
>   **`.CPP, .c++, .cp,`**`or`**`.cxx;`**`C++ header files often use`**`.hh`**`or`**`.H;`**`and`
>   `preprocessed C++ files use the suffix .ii.  GCC recognizes files with`
>   `these names and compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the`
>   `compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the`
>   `name`**`gcc).`**

So, "GCC regocnizes files with these names" and your program was being compiled
as C++ source. I guess that C++ has some special use of `&`, which I can't tell
exactly (I don't know C++). Hence the error.

Now, regarding the difference between `g++` and `gcc`, continue with the next
paragraph:

> `However, the use of`**`gcc`**`does not add the C++ library.`**`g++`**`is a program`
>   `that calls GCC and treats`**`.c, .h`**`and`**`.i`**`files as C++ source files`
>   `instead of C source files unless`**`-x`**`is used, and automatically`
>   `specifies linking against the C++ library.  This program is also useful`
>   `when precompiling a C header file with a`**`.h`**`extension for use in C++`
>   `compilations.  On many systems,`**`g++`**`is also installed with the name`
>   **`c++.`**

On the real question: there aren't two `wait`s here in my system (Darwin 11), only
the standard syscall. Check if what Kevin said isn't happening. It's the same,
*stdlib.h* includes *sys/wait.h*:

```
#include <_types.h>
#if !defined(_ANSI_SOURCE)
#include <sys/wait.h>
#if (!defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE))
#include <alloca.h>
#endif /* (!_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE) */
#endif /* !_ANSI_SOURCE */
```

Check your header.

Comment: Thanks, but "GCC regocnizes files with these names" does not explain why `.c` and `.cpp` are treated in a different way (as the quotes in your post say that all files with these names will be treated as C++ source files). Anyway, +1 for the help and the useful info (:

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: You may want to read it again :-) **g++** treats .c as C++, not **gcc**. And you were compiling with gcc which recognized .cpp as C++. Then you changed to .c and gcc recognized as C.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're damn right :) Sorry, I have missed one part of the first quote. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Kiril : No problems, and glad to help ;-)